# Regex for alternating pattern between two character groups

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to find matches where the pattern alternates between two character groups, D\E and R\K\H.

The pattern I've come up with (through reading other posts on here) is

```
(([DE](?=[RKH])*)|(([RKH])(?=[DE])*))+
```

Using this pattern with this test string: DREDRDRDRARDK

I get the following matches: DR, DRDRD, RD

I want: DRE, DRDRDR, RDK

The matches are missing the last letter for each group.

Please could someone help me figure out why.

Comment: The rules are not clear, could you please add more verbal clarifications?

Answer (score 2):

Match the first group followed by the second with all that matched any number of times and then possibly followed by the first group. i.e. `([DE][RKH])+[DE]?`, or the same with the groups interchanged, i.e. `([RKH][DE])+[RKH]?` or just the first group, i.e. `[DE]` or just the second group, i.e. `[RKH]`:

```
library(gsubfn)

x <- "DREDRDRDRARDK" # input

rx <- "(([DE][RKH])+[DE]?|([RKH][DE])+[RKH]?|[DE]|[RKH])"
strapply(x, rx)
## [[1]]
## [1] "DRE"    "DRDRDR" "RDK"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern, you repeatedly match a single character out of 2 character classes followed by a positive lookahead which asserts that there should be a character present directly at the right.

(**Note** that the positive lookahead should not be optionally repeated `(?=[RKH])*` or else it will always be true, matching too much)

If the quantifier `*` is not present after the lookahead you will get your matches where characters are missing.

The reason why the matches are missing the last letter for each group is when `[DE]` is matched, there is a positive lookahead asserting what is directly to the right is `[RKH]` (and the other way around due to the alternation)

- It does not match the `E` in `DRE` because when matching `E` the lookahead asserts on of `[RKH]` after is, which is not the case
- It does not match the last `R` in `DRDRDR` as there is no `A` following the last `R`
- As the positive lookahead asserts that there should be a next character present, you also don't match the last `K` because there is no character after it

As already answered, you can repeatedly match the pairs of character classes followed by optionally matching the first character class after it.

Without the groups, I think it could also be shortened to:

```
(?:[DE][RKH])+[DE]?|(?:[RKH][DE])+[RKH]?
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w0WYmi/1)

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all("DREDRDRDRARDK", "(?:[DE][RKH])+[DE]?|(?:[RKH][DE])+[RKH]?")
```

Output

```
[[1]]
[1] "DRE"    "DRDRDR" "RDK"
```